# Duplicate LC_RPATH are deprecated

Tags: flutter, dart

I found two warnings when I was trying to build my ios app. Issues are like-

Duplicate LC_RPATH are deprecated ('@executable_path/Frameworks')
Duplicate LC_RPATH are deprecated ('@loader_path/Frameworks')

please give me a solution.

I tried lots of way but couldn't solve it.